# Ajax call does not show response - Zend Framework

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I have some problem with Zend Ajax. That is my js code:

```
function deleteNewsCategory(cId) {
var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the item?");

if(conf) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/ajax/deletenewscategory',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            cId : cId
        },

        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

}

That is my AjaxController:

```
public function init() {
    $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('deletenewscategory', 'json')
            ->initContext();
}

public function deletenewscategoryAction() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        echo $this->_request->getPost('cId');
    }
}
```

I add deleteNewsCategory function in submit button, but when I click this button and appear confirm message and click ok I don't see anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is either a Javascript error preventing the submission from happening, or the response doesn't contain JSON data so your handler isn't being called.

Do you have a view script with the `ajax.phtml` suffix since you are using the Ajax context?

See if adding `exit;` after your echo statement in the `deletenewscategoryAction` results in the alert showing up.

The next thing would be to use Firebug or livehttpheaders for Firefox, or Wireshark to sniff out the HTTP request and response to see what data you are getting back.

Edit:  Since you get a 404 error, try:

```
url: '<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'ajax',
                                  'action'     => 'deletenewscategory'),
                            null, true) ?>',
```

By using the `url()` helper it will construct a URL according to your routes and base path.

The reason your alert isn't showing up is because the 404 contains HTML and not valid JSON, jQuery isn't calling your success handler.

Comment: Don't have javascript error, cId have value, I add alert(1) in success: function (response) { alert(1); ... , but don't see nothing?

Comment: If the HTTP response doesn't contain valid JSON (e.g. it has HTML) then your jQuery callback won't get called.  try removing the `dataType` from the Ajax request, or sniff the full HTTP response using wireshark and see what is coming back.

Comment: Ok I install Wireshark, what I need to search in http?

Comment: Start a capture on the correct network interface, click the button on your webpage and wait a couple seconds for the ajax response to complete.  Then stop wireshark, identify one of the HTTP packets in the list either by protocol, or the IP address of your server, right click any one of those packets and click Follow TCP Stream.  This should then display the entire request and response sequence.  You may need to disable gzip compression on the server if enabled.

Comment: Have problem js function is in .js file not php

Comment: Then in that case you'll just have to figure out the correct URL to put in the file so you don't get a 404 but get your actual controller action.

Comment: I try with $this->url and don't have 404 error but again don't see alert(response) or alert(1)

Comment: Since you said you were in a JS file, `$this->url` won't work.  That is a Zend Framework function and only works from PHP.  What URL do you use to access your ZF app in general?